# Rewrite .html files in Netlify

Tags: redirect, pattern-matching, glob, netlify

I am trying to rewrite patterns like `/abc.html` to `/search?xyz=abc`. 'abc' can be anything.

I've gone through the documentation at https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/

Here's what I have now in my _redirect file, but it doesn't seem to work. Kindly help.

```
/*.html         /search?xyz=:splat        200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer:  I work for netlify

Our [redirects functionality](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/) does not work to do rewrites like that.  Placeholders like slugs (`/blog/:year/:month/:day/:title`) and stars (`/assets/*`) are only matched as full path components - that is, the thing between slashes in a URL or "everything after this / including files in subdirectories".

It's not an uncommon feature request, but our system doesn't work like that right now.

Some ways you can achieve similar goals:

1. usually you aren't intending to redirect existing paths.  [This portion of the docs](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#note-on-shadowing) demonstrates that a standard redirect (`/articles/* /search?xyz=:splat 301`)  will redirect all requests for missing content - be that /articles/1 or /articles/deep/link/that/was/tpyoed.html - to /search with a xyz parameter of the pathname .  This doesn't do exactly what you asked - but it is probably the closest thing and you can hopefully handle the paths appropriately in your /search page.  In case you have any contents under /articles, that will still be served, and not redirected, since you didn't put a `!` on the redirect to force it.
2. if you have a single page app that does its own routing and use a [history pushstate redirect](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps) you could make the router do the right thing for your content since usually there is only one .html page on your site and any other paths would be redirected to it (where the router takes over with whatever smarts you give it)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, very helpful. I've posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50048668/rewrites-with-netlify. Id be very glad if you could answer that too.