# Rewrites with Netlify

Tags: url-rewriting, glob, netlify

I am trying to set up some rewrites in Netlify. Here's what I have in my `_redirects` file:

```
/search xyz=:abc    https://example.com/search?xyz=:abc    200
/:abc               https://example.com/search?xyz=:abc    200
```

The first line works as expected, the second line is not working. However, if I change HTTP status code for the second line to 301, it works. Why is that so? I really need to rewrite like the rule in second line. Is there any other modification I can do to make it work?

Comment: sounds like a bug to me - I'd ping support@netlify.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a response from Netlify email support.

> Passing a path to a redirect as a query param is not meant to work,
>   especially as a 200 status.

So I made some minor changes to my server and this alternative redirect rule works fine:

```
/:abc    https://example.com/search/:abc    200
```